# Kotlin Annotation for autologging a function

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations, annotation-processing

Is it possible to create an Annotation that somehow let my function log automatically on start and end of their execution? Something like:

```
@Log //<-- the custom annotation
fun foo() {
    ...
    log.info("Hello world")
    ...
}
```

with a result of:

```
"Starting execution of function 'foo'"
"Hello world"
"Function 'foo' ended up after 100ms"
```

I'm not an annotation dev expert, so I'm just asking if this is somehow possible, I'm not looking for its implementation.

Comment: Search for `aspect oriented programming`, e.g. the Spring Web Framework uses AspectJ which makes it quite easy to [implement](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-performance-logging) it. Remember: an annotation on its own cannot accomplish this (annotations are just metadata, not functionality), there has to be a component that reads / uses your marker annotation somehow (e.g. Java's `@FunctionalInterface` validation is implemented directly in the Java compiler)

Comment: Thank you @roookeee I'll take a look into that ;)

Comment: There is a library that does what you want: [hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo)

Comment: @gpunto that's for Android only I guess